# Uri builder - why does it delete part of a string?

Tags: android, google-maps

This question is under the context of Android.
So according to Google's documentations this is how we should send a query to a maps app:
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Maps

Or in other words,send it a URI of geo:0,0?q=my+street+address
when we wish to go to my street address

However, if I apply this code:

final String GEO_LOCATION="geo:0,0?";

final String QUERY_PARAM="q";

Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(GEO_LOCATION).buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM,location).build();

builtUri will actually not have 0,0  eg if you check out its String value (to String or debug mode),
the value is geo:?q=.... without 0,0.

While my maps app (Google maps) works perfectly fine without the 0,0, it will be amazing for me to understand what's going on! Why is the 0,0 being deleted? Any way for me to keep it if i want it to be sent with the intention?

Comment: I'd see what `Uri.parse(GEO_LOCATION)` looks like. I would not be surprised if your `0,0` gets lost at that point.

Comment: I did, and actually it doesn't get lost at that point. So I'm assuming appendQueryParameter does it, and i'm not sure why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

geo URIs don't really follow the full rules for URI syntax. geo URIs are "opaque" in that everything after "geo:" is essentially free of the usual URI spec (it can be whatever they want).  In Google's case, they choose to use parameters that look like query strings, but they are not query strings in the sense of the URI spec.  I know, it's weird.

If you want to build an android Uri from an opaque geo URI using as much "proper" code as possible, you could do it like this:

```
float lat = ...
float lon = ...
String addr = URLEncoder.encode("my address", "UTF-8");
java.net.URI(
    "geo",
    "" + lat + "," + lon + "?q=" + addr,
    null);
```

Comment: Hey Doug! Thx for taking your time to answer but now i'm even more confused lol.... you are referring to java's URI which is different than the class Uri(!), i am not sure why?  Isn't google's Uri better in the context of android? On the other hand you are from Google!! lol oh man! Any good guide to Uri vs URI and something to explain why 0,0 disappears? can it affect a different map app?

Comment: I'm just using java's URI as a utility to build a string that can be fed to Android's Uri.  Java URI is a general tool that implements the URI spec.  Android's Uri is mostly just used to locate items in ContentProviders or pass specialized data between app components. (it's not a general purpose tool).  Uri doesn't really fully implement the spec for URI that's accepted by the internet at large.